# How to insert variable from email address in mail()?

Tags: php, email, variables

How do I insert a variable form email address in the PHP mail() function?

```
$form_data =array();
$form_data['firstName'] = 'Joe';
$form_data['surname'] = 'Do';
$form_data['email'] = 'info@Domain';
print "From: ".$form_data['firstName']." ".$form_data['surname']." <".$form_data['email'].">\n";
```

When I wrap <> around then the email address is not displayed
I have tried

```
print "<{$form_data['email']}>";
print '<'.$form_data['email'].'>';
```

But I don't know how to solve this

Complete code (using Wordpres wp_mail() function);

```
        //Send mail
$recipients[] = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
$email_subject = "Contactform - ". get_bloginfo('name');
$email_message = $tpl;      
$headers[] = "From: ".$form_data['firstName']." ".$form_data['surname']." &lt;".$form_data['email']."&gt;\n";       
$headers[] = "Content-Type: text/html\n";
$send =  wp_mail($recipients, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: is the email getting displayed if you dont add < > ?

Comment: No the email address is not displayed when using <>

Comment: Could you post your entire code for the mail() function so we can see where you are inserting these values? The code you have given so far simply outputs the string to HTML which is different to using it in an email header.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `<` and `>` with HTML escaped characters like so:

```
print "From: ".$form_data['firstName']." ".$form_data['surname']." &lt;".$form_data['email']."&gt;\n";
```

`<` = `&lt;` and `>` = `&gt;`

Comment: The question didn't ask for a valid email header, it asked why the email address was not displaying in his `print` command.

Comment: Both methods gives me a unknown sender

    $headers .= "From: {$form_data['firstName']} {$form_data['surname']} ".htmlspecialchars("<".$form_data['email'].">")."\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: {$form_data['firstName']} {$form_data['surname']} &lt;{$form_data['email']}&gt;\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$form_data['firstName']." ".$form_data['surname']." &lt;".$form_data['email']."&gt;\n";

Answer (score 0):

use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) if you want to display it:

```
print "From: ".$form_data['firstName']." ".$form_data['surname']." ".htmlspecialchars("<{$form_data['email']}>");
```